# Using Laravel and Carbon

Tags: php, laravel-4, php-carbon

I have a field in my database called "deadline" which is of DATE format, and I want to use Eloquent to say that if the deadline field does not match `Carbon::now();` but isn't in the future then don't show this row.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select records where `deadline` is greater than or equal to today's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in the `Y-m-d` format.

```
Model::where('deadline','>=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

Laravel works with Carbon for formatting timestamps etc, which you can easily set the `deadline` column as one of those Carbon objects with a Laravel [date mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#date-mutators) allowing you formatting abilities.

But for a select statement, i'd just use the above personally.

Comment: That then only shows two rows, but it should show 5 rows, as it was originally 6 rows but one deadline date is on the 1st Jan 2015

Comment: Ok then you want the opposite of `<=` which is `>=`

Comment: @Lee_S_666 its customary to mark an answer as correct when it is :)

Comment: I can't mark it as not enough rep points. But yeah thanks for this worked a treat.